# How to retrieve the documents containing a specific term followed by another specific term in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I want to retrieve the document containing a specific term followed by another specific term. For example,
I have a index `[index name: demo, type name: demo]` in ElasticSeach, and it has 3 documents, like

```
doc1 "myfield": "AKKARK"
doc2 "myfield": "AKARK"
doc3 "myfield": "AKKAKARK"
```

the field `myfield` set a pattern tokenizer and the tokenizer will split the string after the letter `k`. So the inverted index is

```
AK -> doc1,doc2,doc3
K -> doc1,doc3
ARK -> doc1,doc2,doc3
```

I want to retrieve thoes documents containing `AK` followed by `ARK` and that is `doc2` and `doc3` not `doc1`.
I use `query_string[AND]` and I get `doc1`, `doc2` and `doc3`. This is not what I want. So how to achieve my aim?

DEMO code:

```
PUT demo
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "split_K_analyzer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "(?<=K)",
          "lowercase": false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "demo":{
      "properties": {
        "myfield": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "split_K_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT demo/demo/_bulk
{"index":{"_id" : "doc1"}}
{"myfield": "AKKARK"}
{"index": {"_id": "doc2"}}
{"myfield": "AKARK"}
{"index": {"_id": "doc3"}}
{"myfield": "AKKAKARK"}

GET demo/demo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "myfield",
      "query": "AK AND ARK"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search query returns all documents containing the tokens AK & ARK in the inverted index and this matches all the 3 docs and is working as expected.

If you want to return documents containing AK followed by ARK you should use match_phrase query like below which returns doc2 and doc3 as they contain AK followed by ARK.

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "myfield" : "AKARK"
        }
    }
}
```